# CruiseControl.Net 1.5, htmlReportPlugin, how to make/keep build-specific copies of the html-files?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm using NCover 3.4 (current as of 2010-06-16) to create html reports, which I wish to link to from CCNet.

This article explains how,

http://csut017.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/improved-ncover-integration/

but my build-specific report is not stored in a way that is expected in article(?). At least it does not work for me.

I guess the question is - given a directory with files, how do I get them included in my build-log?

I get reports generated in ./src/coverage/FullCoverageReport during the build.

When I click my report link in dashboard
()

I get

[6:WARN] Unable to find file '74\coverage\FullCoverageReport\fullcoveragereport.html' in 'HealthMonitor'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We abandoned using NCover 3.4 and use NCover 1.5.8 instead. It produces the desired reports in xml, hence the need for html inclusion is no longer there...